# Redirect http requests to https for website hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, ssl, amazon-ec2

The setup: Domain is purchased at Godaddy and the website is hosted in AWS EC2 Instance in a nodejs environment. (SSL is also purchased for https purpose)

Problem: I have setup SSL using the following code:

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
const config = require('./config');
const fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
var redirectApp = express();

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.sslKeyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.sslCertPath),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(config.sslCaPath)
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var redirectServer = http.createServer(redirectApp);

redirectApp.use(function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect('https://www.domain.com'+ req.url);
  }
  next();
});

server.listen(httpsport, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});

redirectServer.listen(httpport, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

After deployment, I am able to access https://www.domain.com and https://domain.com but the http://www.domain.com or http://domain.com requests are not getting forwarded to https version. (server error). Please provide a solution to solve this. I tried forwarding the domain to https version in godaddy and it is of no use.

Answer (score 3):

This will force https on all requests. You may want to put if in front of it to check for an 'dev' or 'production' environment variable.

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      if ((req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https')) {
        res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
      } else
        next();
    });
```

Comment: Not Working @Dave

Comment: @Vignesh copy pasted from code I have running in a few places so it works for me. Maybe explain how it's not working.